# Replace SAN SSL cert on IIS 8.5 swiftly

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-8.5

I have searched in vain to find a solution to this specific query but cannot find a situation identical to mine.

In IIS 8.5, say I have multiple domains, and I have a SAN SSL cert (not wildcard) bound to each one using SNI:

```
a.domain.com
b.domain.com
c.domain.com
```

If I wanted to add `d.domain.com` and generate a new SAN that includes the new domain, I want to be able to replace the current cert without having to re-bind the new one to the 3 above domains (I can then manually bind the new 4th domain).

Now imagine in my example above that I actually have 20 domains - it's fairly time-consuming to do this, especially if you add a new site every couple of weeks - not to mention the downtime whilst I re-bind the SSL site-per-site.

Is there a solution I can apply to automate this process? I could envisage a PS script doing it provided I have the new cert's hash, but my PS-fu is not strong enough to work out how to iterate through all the sites and re-apply the cert (if that's how it needs to be done). Ideally it would be a solution that automatically imports the new cert (.pfx), removes the old one, and rebinds the sites.

**EDIT:** To confirm, I'm using one IP address for all sites.

Comment: And for further confirmation, you are using a single IP for all the sites?

Comment: yes I am - will add to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste the following functions into your PowerShell window:

```
function Get-IisSslBinding{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)] [Alias("fi","sn")]
        [string]$FilterBySiteName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] [Alias("co")] [ValidateNotnullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$ComputerName=$env:ComputerName
    )
    Begin{
        Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Load Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly...")
        $null=[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
    }
    Process{
        Foreach($computer in $ComputerName){
            Try{
                If($computer -eq "$env:ComputerName"){
                    Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Open connection to local computer [ {0} ]..." -f $computer)
                    $webServer=New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
                    $null=$webServer
                }
                Else{
                    Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Open connection to remote computer [ {0} ]..." -f $computer)
                    $webServer=[Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote($computer)
                }
                # filter sites
                $sites=($webServer.Sites | Where{$_.Name -match $FilterBySiteName})
                Foreach($site in $sites){
                    Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Get binding(s) for [ {0} ]..." -f $site.Name)
                    # filter bindings
                    $siteHttpsBindings=($site.Bindings | Where{$_.Protocol -eq "https"})
                    Foreach($siteHttpsBinding in $siteHttpsBindings){
                        Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Get binding information ...")
                        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                            'ComputerName'=$computer.ToUpper()
                            'SiteId'=$site.ID 
                            'SiteName'=$site.Name
                            'BindingInformation'=$siteHttpsBinding.GetAttributeValue("bindinginformation")
                            'Thumbprint'=$siteHttpsBinding.GetAttributeValue("certificateHash")
                            'CertificateStore'=$siteHttpsBinding.GetAttributeValue("certificateStoreName")
                            'Protocol'=$siteHttpsBinding.GetAttributeValue("protocol")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Catch{
                Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - ERROR - {0}" -f $_.Exception.GetBaseException().Message)
            }
            Finally{
                Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Dispose web server resources...")
                $webServer.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    End{
        Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Done")
    }
}
##
function Set-IisSslBinding{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] [Alias("oh")] [ValidateNotnullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Thumbprint,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [Alias("nh")] [ValidateNotnullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$AfterThumbprint,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] [Alias("sn")] [ValidateNotnullOrEmpty()]
        $SiteName,
        [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] [Alias("co")] [ValidateNotnullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$ComputerName=$env:ComputerName
    )
    Begin{
        Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Load Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly...")
        $null=[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
    }
    Process{
        Foreach($computer in $ComputerName){
            Try{
                If($computer -eq "$env:ComputerName"){
                    Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Open connection to local computer [ {0} ]..." -f $computer)
                    $webServer=New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
                    $IsCertificateInStore=((Get-ChildItem -Path CERT:\LocalMachine\My) -match $AfterThumbprint)
                }
                Else{
                    Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Open connection to remote computer [ {0} ]..." -f $computer)
                    $webServer=[Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote($computer)
                }
                # If(-not $IsCertificateInStore){
                    # Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - The computer [ {0} ] does not contain the certificate [ {1} ]... " -f $computer,$AfterThumbprint)
                    # Break
                # }
                Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Filter sites...")
                $sites=($webServer.Sites|where{$_.Name -match $SiteName})
                Foreach($site in $sites){
                    #filter bindings
                    $siteHttpsBindings=($site.Bindings|where{$_.Protocol -eq "https"})
                    Foreach($siteHttpsBinding in $siteHttpsBindings){
                        Switch($siteHttpsBinding.GetAttributeValue("certificateHash")){
                            $Thumbprint{
                                Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Remove old certificate [ {0} ]... " -f $siteHttpsBinding.GetAttributeValue("certificateHash"))
                                $BindingMethod=$siteHttpsBinding.Methods["RemoveSslCertificate"]
                                $BindingMethodInstance=$BindingMethod.CreateInstance()
                                $BindingMethodInstance.Execute()
                                Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Add new certificate [ {0} ]..." -f $AfterThumbprint)
                                $BindingMethod=$siteHttpsBinding.Methods["AddSslCertificate"]
                                $BindingMethodInstance=$BindingMethod.CreateInstance()
                                $BindingMethodInstance.Input.SetAttributeValue("certificateHash", $AfterThumbprint)
                                $BindingMethodInstance.Input.SetAttributeValue("certificateStoreName", "My")
                                $BindingMethodInstance.Execute()
                                New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                                    'ComputerName'=$computer.ToUpper()
                                    'SiteId'=$site.ID 
                                    'SiteName'=$site.Name
                                    'BindingInformation'=$siteHttpsBinding.GetAttributeValue("bindingInformation")
                                    'Thumbprint'=$siteHttpsBinding.GetAttributeValue("certificateHash")
                                    'PreviousThumbprint'=$Thumbprint
                                }
                            }
                            Default{
                                Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Could not get https binding(s) attribute for [ {0} ]" -f $site.Name)
                                break
                            }
                        }                
                    }
                }
            }
            Catch{
                Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - ERROR - {0}" -f $_.Exception.GetBaseException().Message)
            }
            Finally{
                Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Dispose web server resources...")
                $webServer.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    End{
        Write-Verbose ("$(Get-Date) - INFO - Done.")
    }
}
```

Then execute:

1. To list all the sites and their bindings:

`Get-IisSslBinding`

2. To update all the sites and their SSL bindings:

`Get-IisSslBinding | Set-IisSslBinding -AfterThumbprint AAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC`

** Ensure the new SSL certificate is already in the SSL store. Also the `Get-IisSslBinding` function as a `-FilterBySiteName` param so you can target the exact site(s) you might need to touch.

Comment: Glad to assist. Also the `Set-IisSslBinding` function is not dependent on the `Get-IisSslBinding` function. It can be used like so too `Set-IisSslBinding -Thumbprint AAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC -AfterThumbprint XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZ -SiteName "The Exact Site Name" `. And if you have the site on multiple computers, you could add the parameter like so `-ComputerName WEB-SERVER001,WEB-SERVER002`

Comment: awsome script bud. I found these helpful to: ```
Get-IisSslBinding | where-object {$_.BindingInformation -like "*.certname"} | where-object {$_.Thumbprint -ne "OLD HASH"}
```